# Add class properties from the List and put them into the string together with a comma as a delimiter

Tags: c#, arraylist, system.reflection

Although the thing I want to do seems be really trivial I can not find a way to achieve what I want. I know there exist multiple questions how to put class properties into the list together and separate it by a comma like that on SO, but none of them seemed to be relevant to my case.

I have a class `Form` defined as follows:

```
public class Form
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAdress { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public string OfficeAdress { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public Boolean FunctionalTest { get; set; }
        public string Signature { get; set; }


        public Form()
        {
        }
    }
```

In the `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I create a `List<Form>` with the `Form` class properties and subsequently I would like to create a string with all of those class properties separated by a comma. For that case I use basic `Join` method with Select which converts any kinds of objects to string.

I do that by `createCSV` method inside `MainPage.xaml.cs` :

```
void createCSV()
        {    
            var records = new List<Form>
        {
            new Form {CustomerName = customerName.Text,
                CustomerAdress = customerAdress.Text,
                CustomerNumber = customerNumber.Text,
                OfficeAdress = officeAdress.Text,
                Date = date.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
                FunctionalTest = testPicker.ToString()=="YES" ? true : false,
                Signature = signature.Text
            }
        };


            string results = String.Join(",", (object)records.Select(o => o.ToString()));
}
```

The problem is instead of the desirable outcome which is:`"Mark Brown,123 High Level Street,01578454521,43 Falmouth Road,12/15/2020,false,Brown"`

I am getting: `"System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator'2[MyApp.Form,System.String]"`

PS. As you have noticed I am newbie in C#. Instead of non constructive criticism of the code, please for a valuable reply which would help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to create a CSV file of your data, using CSVHelper would probably be a better approach

Comment: Yes I was fiddling with CSVHelper as well. It was working perfectly fine, but the only one issue was I've had to provide an absolute path to make it work and I need a  relative one on which I couldn't make it work

Comment: see the docs on files in Xamarin - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Form` class, You can override the ToString() method and use `System.Reflection` to get your comma string.

**Form.cs**

```
public class Form
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAdress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string OfficeAdress { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public bool FunctionalTest { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string modelString = string.Empty;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Form).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(this); // you should add a null check here before doing value.ToString as it will break on null
            modelString += value.ToString() + ",";
        }
        return modelString;
    }
}
```

Code

```
List<string> CSVDataList = new List<string>();
List<Form> FormList = new List<Form>();
...
foreach (var data in FormList)
{
    CSVDataList.Add(data.ToString());
}
```

Now you have a list of string `CSVDataList` with each `Form` object's data in comma style

**P.S.**
for DateTime

```
var value = property.GetValue(this);
if(value is DateTime date)
{
   modelString += date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ",";
}
```